# Unavailability of features in App

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, android-app

Why don't we have a large section of the  features available in the Android App of MathSE?

You cannot delete your own answer, review posts, see most of your posts except the top Q's and A's and much more.

Comment: This is relevant to all SE sites so probably more suitable for Meta-Meta. Related questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app ; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233669/allow-us-to-vote-to-reopen-from-the-android-app ;

Comment: That said, [Why has Stack Exchange stopped working on the Android app?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272122/why-has-stack-exchange-stopped-working-on-the-android-app)

Comment: I use the mobile version of the website in chrome instead of the app. Although honestly I don't recommend SE in a phone altogether